# How to get Symfony to read env variables from another file other than .env?

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

Symfony isn't reading the environmental variables from the config / parameters even though they exist in the running docker container environment.

Symfony keeps complaining if specifically the `.env` file isn't used.

How do I get Symfony to read the environment itself, or a file named other than `.env`?

Some more information:

The issue arises in ./symfony/dependency-injection/EnvVarProcessor.php:96 when it's trying to load files from the `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` for use in the Doctrine ORM.

Comment: if i understand , you want to create another file nammed other than .env to declare env variable inside ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Yes OR for Symfony to read variables from the docker environment variables

Comment: whish symfony version you are using ?

Comment: Symphony 4.0 is the version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**. Reading env variable from docker env variable

As you know, symfony can read env variable only those are prefixed by **SYMFONY__**

In the DockerFile :

```
ENV SYMFONY__MY_ENV_VAR myvalue // here  it's not forced to prefix it by SYMFONY__
```

In the apache file conf where you configure your virtual host for example :

```
 SetEnv SYMFONY__MY_ENV_VAR ${SYMFONY__MY_ENV_VAR} // ${SYMFONY__MY_ENV_VAR} refer to the previous variable declared in docker file
```

in you parameters.yml

```
  parameters: 
     my_env_value: '%my.env_var%'
```

Symfony will replace dot  with the two underscore to find the env var without the keyword **symfony__**.

**Example:**

```
SYMFONY__MY_ENV_VAR  ==> %my_env_var%
```

So in your application you need just to inject the container to get the parameter like this way :

```
$this->container->getParameter('my_env_value');
```

**2.** Override .env file with another filename

The point here is to modify your bootstrap.php file that looks like :

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
// Load cached env vars if the .env.local.php file exists
// Run "composer dump-env prod" to create it (requires symfony/flex >=1.2)
if (is_array($env = @include dirname(__DIR__).'/.env.local.php')) {
    $_SERVER += $env;
    $_ENV += $env;
} elseif (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Please run "composer require symfony/dotenv" to load the ".env" files configuring the application.');
} else {
    // load all the .env files
    (new Dotenv())->loadEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env'); // just make the file name that you want instead of .env
}
$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = $_ENV['APP_ENV'] = ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? $_ENV['APP_ENV'] ?? null) ?: 'dev';
$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] = $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? $_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] ?? 'prod' !== $_SERVER['APP_ENV'];
$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] = $_ENV['APP_DEBUG'] = (int) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] || filter_var($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ? '1' : '0';
```

Comment: I added some more information in the OP. These environmental variables are for use in the Doctrine ORM, so I won't be using any PHP directly like that to get them.

Comment: you mean the first option , i mean env file nammed something unlike to .env ?

Comment: why don't you use the .env ? do you have a restriction about that ?

Comment: There is a restriction. Ideally I want to use environmental variables first, but either method is acceptable.

Comment: @yellowarchangel check my answer

Comment: Hey mohammed, that seems good! I ended up just using the .env file, but this looks good and I'll give it a shot!